Warped MTB Tyres
I recently bought a used Canyon Spectral, which came with Maxxis minion and highroller 27.5 x 2.3 TR tyres. Both tyres appear to be  warped. The rims are fine and I’ve tried installing with several new inner tubes, so it’s not them either. New tyres roll perfectly btw. I have also seated the old tyres correctly using the guide line and tried the hot soapy water trick whilst seating. I can only assume the tyres are warped and useless, which is a shame because there is plenty of life left in the tread. Does anyone know if there’s a way of bringing these back life or do I bin them (recycle obviously)?
Not sure what good images are as you won't see the wobble but here's some.


Welcome to the site - Could you please add a couple photos showing the warped tyres?   Did they roll badly when installed or is it a visual thing ?

Did you use a tire lever to mount the tires as you were swapping tubes?

Also, warped tires are annoying, but as you say, “they roll fine”. Therefore they’re not useless.

I will add photos but you won’t be able to see the wobble without a video and I don’t think you can add video on this site. The tyres were inherited. I have had them off several times in order to refit. The problem persists. Yes I did use a tyre lever when swapping tubes. Just to clarify- I have new tyres which roll perfectly, it’s the old ones that are warped. If they can be ‘fixed’ I would like to keep them.

Warping is annoying, but it won’t after the performance of the tire. If the tread is good, keep using them. And to prevent warping in the future, learn how to mount tires without using tools.

Cheers for the responses and advice.
